# Unable to install latest version of cocoapods using homebrew.Always installing cocoapods1.5.2 in MacOS Catlina 10.15.7

Tags: cocoapods, homebrew

brew install cocoapods

pod --version
1.5.2

Not able to update to latest version 1.10.1

Comment: Hi cinvin, Were you able to solve this issue

Comment: i'm facing the same issue